# Storing k people's phone numbers in n locations using hash function.

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Assuming no two people have the same name and locations are chosen at random, what is the probability that at least one location has more than one phone number stored there? (From Introduction to Probability, Blitzstein and Hwang, Pg 35)

I figured this is one of those questions where we should find the complement of the stated event and then subtract from 1.

I think that the number of possible ways to store numbers without overlap is the same as sampling without replacement the locations $n!/(n-k)!$ and the total number of possible ways to store numbers in any way is the same as sampling with replacement the locations $n^k$. So the probability of no overlap should be:
$$n!/(n-k)!n^k$$

and the probability of at least one overlap is then:
$$1-(n!/(n-k)!n^k)$$

Have I reasoned through this correctly? It seems at least that the probability goes up as n gets closer to k, which makes sense intuitively (I tested with n=4 and two different k values: 2,4).

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, and well articulated.